# Fetching extra char[] data from the Intent returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

In my I have two activites, Each Activity has a button saying `Add to Home Screen`.

When user taps on this button I am creating a shortcut for my app which will open that particular Activity from which it was added to the home screen.

While creating the shortcut I want to put some extra data in the intent which will invoke the particular Activity. For this I am using the following code:

```
final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
char CharData[] = new char[5];
Arrays.fill(CharData,'1');
shortcutIntent.putExtra("Extra", CharData);

final Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.First_Shortcut_Title));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.red));
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");   
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

From this I am able to create the shortcut on my home screen and navigate to the appropriate activity as required. The problem I am facing is when I try to fetch the extra data from the Intent when Activity is lunched it always retun a `Null`.

```
Intent CallingIntent = getIntent();
char[] IntentData = CallingIntent.getCharArrayExtra("Extra");
```

i.e. value of `IntentData` is always `NULL`.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong ?

I have tried similar thing with the a `String` instead of a `char[]` array and it is working fine. what may be wrong with the array implementation ?

Comment: is the key `shape`? Does it match?

Comment: Actually by mistake I have put wrong key while asking the question. I have corrected my question now. In code both the keys are matching and still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'r key is wrong while retrieving the array data.

Wrong value is:

```
 char[] IntentData = CallingIntent.getCharArrayExtra("shape");
```

Right value is:

```
 char[] IntentData = CallingIntent.getCharArrayExtra("Extra");
```